# Создать форму radio в которой будут списком выводиться из базы данных все записи. PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Как создать форму, где будут выводиться все пользователи сайта из базы, чтоб можно было выбрать пользователя для редактирования его полей в базе?  Пробовал вот так, не получается.

```
<form action="index/func" method="post">
<?php
$row = $this->db->prepare('SELECT id, login, password FROM users');
$row->execute();
$row->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
do
{
    printf("<input type='radio' name='user' value='%s'>%s %s<br/><br/>", $row['id'], $row['login'],  $row['password']); 
}
while( $row->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
?>
<input type="submit" value="Выбрать элемент">
</form>
```

Comment: взять и создать, написать код.

Answer (score 1):

Выводить в radio думается плохо, вот вывод в список. Если очень хочется просто замените на radio.

```
$smth = $db->query('SELECT id, login, password FROM users');
while($row = $smth ->fetch()){ 
    echo "<option value = ".$row['id'].'">'.$row['login'].'</option>';
}
```